# Update Record in before trigger

Tags: trigger, validation, field-update, before-trigger

I have one trigger on Opportunity which will copy the value of some Account field into opportunity field. All I'm doing in before trigger because I also have validation rule on opportunity which will fire on opportunity.

But in before trigger my values are not getting updated.
here is my code:

```
for(Opportunity op : Trigger.New){

    op.Checkbox1 = op.Account.Wal_Checkbox1;
    op.Checkbox2 = op.Account.Wal_Checkbox2;
    op.Checkbox3 = op.Account.Wal_Checkbox3;
    op.Checkbox4 = op.Account.Wal_Checkbox4;

}
```

Comment: Just use formula fields. No need for a trigger

Comment: due to some business login I can't move them to formula

Comment: What business logic? The value will be the same regardless if they are populated via trigger or as a formula field. Maybe the business logic is flawed or misunderstood

Answer (score 2):

In `Trigger.New` (Context variables), you can not reference relationship object fields. Ex: Opportunity.Account.Name. In Trigger `Name` will not be available.

- You will need to perform separate query to get those fields from Account.
- Use some collection like `Map<Id,Account>` to have Opportunity's
  Account Id and its Account in a map.
- When you iterate opportunity (Trigger.New), pass the Opportunity's Account Id to get
  Account fields
- Assign those fields in relevant Opportunity fields.

Comment: Earlier I was doing same thing but it was not working
List<Id> accListId = new List<Id>
for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.New){
            accListId.add(opp.AccountId);
}

Comment: for(Opportunity op : [Select Id,Account.Checkbox4,Account.Checkbox3,Account.Checkbox2,
                                Account.Checkbox1,Checkbox4,Checkbox1,
                                Checkbox3,Checkbox2 from Opportunity where AccountId IN : accListId]){
            system.debug('..33.. '+op);
            
            if(op.Account.Checkbox4 != null){
                op.Checkbox4 = op.Account.Checkbox4;
            }                        
        }

Comment: @salesforceDeveloper You don't need to query Opportunity, query Account based on Ids present in Opportunity AccountId. We need Account fields.

Comment: more precisely, in your first sentence: In `Trigger.new`, you cannot  reference relationship ...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to query your Account records, don't think you can reference Account attributes from the record returned by Trigger directly